# Typescript call a javascript function in current scope

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm migrating a project from JS to Typescript. But new TS class should coexist with previous JS. There is a function in scope called verifyActivityChange(). In javascript this function has been declared in the app.js file and can be called from anywhere.

How do I call this function from a Typescript class ?

In some TS file I was able to do

```
    // @ts-ignore
    import * as appjs from "./app.js";
    appjs.verifyActivityChange();
```

Note sure if this is correct since I had to ignore compilation error. But if I'm doing the same  process within a class I have an error appjs dosn't have a constructor.

Edit How do I call the function from the class

```
    import {verifyActivityChange} from "./app.js";
    
    export class ViewController {
    
        public update(){
    
    verifyActivityChange(); //how can I call this function ? it's on my page DOM

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can import JS files in TS code, but you have to do inform the compiler that you are trying to do this. You can either compile with the `--allowJs` option (read more [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)) or specify this in the `tsconfig.json` file, read more [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html))

Comment: then I think the question is more about the scope. How can I call the function from a typescript class ? Knowing the app.js has been included in the index.html

Comment: Note I had to convert app.js to a module otherwise I couldn't import typescript classes